# Improving overblown out Christmas lights

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I'm quite surprised by the very poor performance of my iPhone 13 Pro Max when taking pictures of my girls tonight. The highlights of the blue LED lights were overexposed, causing faces and other things to flatten or look posterized. Something really went wrong with my camera's processing. Is there any technique to reset the processing to allow the AI to make better choices? Here's a sample of the lights.

[image]

Comment: Does it change if you disable Night Mode?

Comment: @MarcWilson these weren't night mode photos.